# “…performed every year "on" Horse Guards Parade”

Tags: prepositions, dates

How come it's "on Horse Guards Parade" instead of "at Horse Guards Parade" in the following phrase? Thank you!

> "[Trooping the Colour](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trooping_the_Colour) is a ceremonial event performed every year on Horse Guards Parade in London, United Kingdom, by regiments of Household Division, to celebrate the official birthday of the British sovereign."

Source: Wikipedia

Comment: If you thought that Horse Guard Parade referred to a specific date, like saying "on St. Valentine's" or "on Bank holiday" it might have possible. But clicking on the first link in the Wikipedia article you would have read: [Horse Guards Parade is **a large parade ground** off Whitehall in central London . **It is the site** of the annual ceremonies of Trooping the Colour,…](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horse_Guards_Parade) I would have asked why is **on** used instead of **in**? We say in a park/ in a garden/ in a street etc.

Comment: In case someone objects, if a street is not named we use "in" such as "He is used to being [recognized in the street](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/street_1)." This would have been a great question if you had explained why you thought "at" should have been used. Sometimes explaining your confusion can generate better and more detailed answers.

Comment: Why do you think it should be *at*? Please explain your problem in the question or we may not be able to solve it.

Answer (score 2):

Horse Guards Parade is a large **parade ground** in London. It's the name of the open space where the parade is held. So, it's correct to use "on".

Comment: Not a road but a large open space, on whose surface the parade takes place.

Comment: @KateBunting Thank you. I've edited the answer.

Answer (score 1):

We can, and often do, use the preposition 'on' to talk about some types of location.

> We also use on for lines (including rivers, borders, streets, etc.)
> and islands.
>
> *London is on the River Thames.*
>
> *The Pyrenees are on the border of Spain and France.*
>
> ***There's a market on James Street**.*
>
> *I'd love to live on the Isle of Wight.*

[Prepositions of place (British Council LearnEnglish)](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/grammar/a1-a2-grammar/prepositions-place#:%7E:text=We%20use%20on%20to%20talk,are%20pictures%20on%20the%20wall.)

Answer (score 1):

From the official [Royal Parks.org UK](https://www.royalparks.org.uk/visit/parks/st-jamess-park/horse-guards-parade)

The preposition "[at](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/at?q=at)" could be used if we consider Horse Guards Parade a specific location where we can find, or see things

#### There are a number of memorials located at Horse Guards Parade:

- Royal Naval Division Memorial
- Viscount Wolseley Statue
- Earl Roberts Statue
- Lord Kitchener Statue
- Lord Mountbatten Statue

Answer (score -3):

It seems incorrect. The wrong preposition.
I'm British and was born here and have lived here for 40 years. Can you name the journalist who wrote the text? -- "at" would probably be the natural L1 choice.

"...performed ON Horse Guards" suggests grammatically that we are performing something on them. Poor guys.